# ¿Como restaurar un Programa oculto desde otro?

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando una herramienta la cual por medio de un botón se puede ocultar, quedando en segundo plano y mostrando un ícono en el show hidden icons.

También al momento del usuario volver a querer ejecutar la herramienta esta valida en la clase Program si ya hay una instancia corriendo y evita duplicar ventana:

```
private static bool getPrevInstance()
{
   //get the name of current process, i,e the process 
   //name of this current application

   string currPrsName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

   //Get the name of all processes having the 
   //same name as this process name 
   Process[] allProcessWithThisName = Process.GetProcessesByName(currPrsName);

   //if more than one process is running return true.
   //which means already previous instance of the application 
   //is running
   if (allProcessWithThisName.Length > 1)
   {                                      
      return true; // Yes Previous Instance Exist
   }
   else
   {
      return false; //No Prev Instance Running
   }
}
```

Lo que quiero es que si ya hay una instancia en segundo plano abierta, restaure la ventana de esta.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! busco sobre SetForegroundWindow... pero vas a tener que adivinar cual es tu Id y cual el del otro proceso...

Comment: Quizá puedas hacer algo con [`MainWindowHandle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle) y [`ShowWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) (en Windows).

Comment: Observación: Está bien comentar el código. Pero veo que tienes muchos comentarios. Siempre es mejor escribir código que se entienda por sí solo y poner comentarios en lugares que no quede claro.

Comment: fijate si [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50552592/73749) no te sirve...

Comment: @gbianchi Mil Gracias, en este hilo pude encontrar el siguiente linkcon el cual pude solucionarlo: 

[Code Proyect](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32908/C-Single-Instance-App-With-the-Ability-To-Restore)